# Strange python function return while dealing with json

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, list

I have a **json_data** object like below:

```
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "id": "49704565-7d73-11eb-9457-cc3d8278f653",
      "name": { "singular": "category", "plural": "category" },
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "49704564-7d73-11eb-b772-cc3d8278f653",
          "name": { "singular": "product", "plural": "products" },
          "relation": { "entity": "" },
          "type": "relation_many"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "49704563-7d73-11eb-90f8-cc3d8278f653",
      "name": { "singular": "product", "plural": "product" },
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "49704562-7d73-11eb-9d41-cc3d8278f653",
          "name": { "singular": "category", "plural": "categories" },
          "relation": { "entity": "" },
          "type": "relation_one"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "ProjetCRA"
  }
}
```

Now, I define 2 function to get "id of table" as well as "id of field" belong to specific table:

```
def get_tbl_id(tbl_name, json_data):
    tbl_id = ""
    for e in json_data['tables']:
        if (e['name']['singular'] == tbl_name):
            tbl_id = e['id']
    return tbl_id
```

```
def get_field_id(field_name, tbl_name, json_data):
    field_id = ""
    for e in json_data['tables']:
        if (e['name']['singular'] == tbl_name):
            for f in e['fields']:
                if (f['name']['singular'] == field_name):
                    field_id = f['id']
    return field_id
```

I can run these below command and it return exactly what I want:

```
get_tbl_id('category', json_data)                => "49704565-7d73-11eb-9457-cc3d8278f653"
get_tbl_id('product', json_data)                 => "49704563-7d73-11eb-90f8-cc3d8278f653"
get_field_id('product', 'category', json_data)   => "49704564-7d73-11eb-b772-cc3d8278f653"
get_field_id('category', 'product', json_data)   => "49704562-7d73-11eb-9d41-cc3d8278f653"
```

Now, I have a string

```
str_args = "cagetory-relation_many,product,product"
```

I will split it out:

```
table_need_to_update = str_args.split('-')[0]
table_will_be_refer_to = str_args.split('-')[1].split(',')[2]
```

If I run it from the command, I will get:

```
table_need_to_update => 'category'
table_will_be_refer_to => 'product'
```

However, if I run:

```
get_tbl_id(table_need_to_update , json_data) 
get_tbl_id(table_will_be_refer_to , json_data)
```

I will get empty string for the first result:

[image: Error]

I have no idea why, although the string **table_need_to_update** is **'category'**, and If I run explicitly the parameter '**category**', it work. Please take a look and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the string

str_args = "cagetory-relation_many,product,product"

Here you have a typo -> **cagetory**. It should be **category** I believe.

That is reason why `get_tbl_id(table_need_to_update , json_data)` is returning empty.

Comment: My bad, takes me 2 hours until now to figure out that simple typo